# in React Table, how to update the drop down value in every row separately using state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

new to react state.looping through dynamic JSON response and creating the dynamic table, which has drop-down as well. If I update the value in the row number 1 with onSelect event it is updating the select value in all the row because of the single state maintained for all the row. How to create a separate state for each row?

```
const statusValue = ["Approve", "Reject"];
const statusValues = statusValue.map((data, i) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      eventKey={data + "-" + i}
      key={"status-" + i}
      onSelect={this.onStatusChange}>
      {data}
    </MenuItem>
  );
});
<DropdownButton
  id="schemaType"
  key="schemaTypeDropdown"
  bsStyle="default"
  title={this.state.statusAction}
  className="mr-3">
  {" "}
  {statusValues}{" "}
</DropdownButton>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can maintain object with key being unique value and on change of dropdown you can change that specific value in that object **OR** better way is Create a new component for each row, pass data in that row using `props`, and maintain dropdown and state in that `Row` component.

```
// example parent, maintain dropdown state in child `Row`
<Parent>
   {data.map(item => <Row data={item} />)}
</Parent>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the example, if possible?

Comment: As you can see onSelect I m changing the status, how to make it unique for the row?

Comment: would you mind adding your code in question ?

Comment: I have added the code in the question itself